# Converting CharSequence[] and CharSequence[]

Tags: java, android

I always thought CharSequence[] and String[] were essential the same, however :

I have some code that has the following :

```
CharSequence[] mEntries;
...
String[] mEntriesString = (String[]) mEntries;
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.two_lines_list_preference_row, mEntriesString)
```

When the code runs I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.CharSequence[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
```

So two questions ?

- why can this cast not happen
- why does the ArrayAdapter not allow for a CharSequence[] in it's constructor.

Comment: nothing prevent an arrayadapter to use a CharSequence[] as a parameter.

Comment: When I try I get the following : The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, CharSequence[]) is undefined

Comment: why don't you use `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` ?

Comment: as @jlordo pointed out, you type your arrayadapter with String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CharSequence` is interface which `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` classes implements. So `CharSequence` can hold any of this implementation class's Object And `CharSequence#toString` returns `String`, try -

```
String[] mEntriesString = new String[mEntries.length];
int i=0;
for(CharSequence ch: mEntries){
    mEntriesString[i++] = ch.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: (not by me so i can only guess, but I'd say it's because it's useless and overkill?)

Answer (score 1):

`CharSequence` is an Interface. `String` class implements that interface. So, you cannot cast it to `String`, the same way you cannot cast `List` to `ArrayList`, because it doesn't have to be an instance of that concrete class

Comment: You can cast `List` to `ArrayList`, the `ClassCastException` will **only** happen if the referenced object is not of type `ArrayList`. See: `List list = new ArrayList(); ArrayList a = (ArrayList) list; LinkedList b = (LinkedList) list;` The first cast will work, the second one will fail.

Comment: @jlordo yes, I agree. I should've wrote that you cannot cast it SAFELY, unless you use instanceof operator

Answer (score 1):

You can not cast reference `CharSequence[]` into `String[]`.

You can cast it only in that situation:

```
        CharSequence[] charSequencesAsString = new String[] { "test" };
        String[] result = (String[]) charSequencesAsString;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Safe way to solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CharSequence[] charSequencesAsString = new String[] { "test" };
    CharSequence[] charSequencesAsCharSequence = new CharSequence[] { "test" };
    CharSequence[] charSequencesAsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder[] { new StringBuilder("Test") };

    String[] stringsFromStrings = convertToStringArray(charSequencesAsString);
    String[] stringsFromCharSequence = convertToStringArray(charSequencesAsCharSequence);
    String[] stringsFromStringBuilder = convertToStringArray(charSequencesAsStringBuilder);

    System.out.println("Same array after conversion: " + (stringsFromStrings == charSequencesAsString));
    System.out.println("Same array after conversion: " + (stringsFromCharSequence == charSequencesAsCharSequence));
    System.out.println("Same array after conversion: " + (stringsFromStringBuilder == charSequencesAsStringBuilder));
}

public static String[] convertToStringArray(CharSequence[] charSequences) {
    if (charSequences instanceof String[]) {
        return (String[]) charSequences;
    }

    String[] strings = new String[charSequences.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < charSequences.length; index++) {
        strings[index] = charSequences[index].toString();
    }

    return strings;
}
```